# SPFX webpart referencing images in html

Tags: html, sharepoint, spfx

I'm creating a simple SharePoint webpart using SPFX, I wanna reference images in the solution.
I used this method:

```
require("@microsoft/loader-set-webpack-public-path!");

<img src="${require<string>('../../assets/logo.jpg')}" alt="My Company" />
```

But it doesn't work.

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sample test demo:

No framework:

```
<img src="${require<string>('../../download.jpg')}" alt="My Company" />
```

[image]

React framework:

[image]

```
<img src={require('../../assets/panda.jpg')} alt="test" />
```